# steam won't launch

Tags: arch-linux, steam

steam can install but failled to launch :

i've checked archlinux wiki, asked chatgpt, searched net for anwsers but none could resolve my situation :

the laucher write this errors :

````
steam.sh[58694]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[58768]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[58694]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared 
object file): ignored.
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Startup - updater built Jul 10 2023 23:58:24
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Startup - Steam Client launched with: 
'/home/gy0m/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam'   
07/29 22:44:04 Init: Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1689034492)/tid(58892)
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Loading cached metrics from disk 
(/home/gy0m/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 
'baked in'
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Checking for update on startup
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Checking for available updates...
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/st … t_ubuntu12
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Manifest download: send request
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Manifest download: waiting for download to finish
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Manifest download: finished
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1689034492, installed version 
1689034492, existing pending version 0
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Nothing to do
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Verifying installation...
[2023-07-29 22:44:04] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2023-07-29 22:44:05] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 3.0.0-1782-g214d5daa3
XRRGetOutputInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf1233db0
XRRGetCrtcInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf1232500
/usr/share/themes/Sweet-Dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:727: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
/usr/share/themes/Sweet-Dark/gtk-2.0/apps/chrome.rc:50: error: invalid string constant "button", expected valid 
string constant
/usr/share/themes/Sweet-Dark/gtk-2.0/apps/xfce.rc:79: error: invalid string constant "entry", expected valid string constant
GetWin32Stats: display was not open yet, good
GetWin32Stats: display was not open yet, good
steamwebhelper.sh[58972]: Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to /home/gy0m/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
steamwebhelper.sh[58972]: glibc >= 2.34, partially disabling sandbox until CEF supports clone3()
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize
Warning: failed to set thread priority: set failed for 8: -1: setpriority() failed
Warning: failed to set thread priority: set failed for priority 8
Warning: support for elevated priorities is most likely unavailable, suppressing future warnings
Warning: failed to set thread priority: set failed for 8: -1: setpriority() failed
Warning: failed to set thread priority: set failed for 8: -1: setpriority() failed
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
Assertion 'device' failed at src/libsystemd/sd-device/device-private.c:103, function device_get_tags_generation(). Aborting.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
crash_20230729224406_27.dmp[59180]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20230729224406_27.dmp
crash_20230729224406_27.dmp[59180]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
crash_20230729224406_27.dmp[59180]: error: Couldn't resolve host name
crash_20230729224406_27.dmp[59180]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20230729224406_27.dmp'', upload no: ''Couldn't resolve host name''
/home/gy0m/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh : ligne 798 : 58892 Abandon                 (core dumped)"$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@" ```
````

Comment: With Arch, when a thing doesn’t work it’s usually because I didn’t follow the Wiki to the letter. I suggest you revisit the installation instructions for steam and check for what you have possibly missed. The first thing is to do a full upgrade `pacman -Syu` before you install steam

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure it's the right way to do but it worked for me :
i installed steam-native-runtime ... in archlinux  :

`pacman -S  steam-native-runtime`

i'm not quite sure what it done but it fixed my problems with this command.

i hope it can help someone with the same errors like me.